# Finding Error in Following C Programme- how to correct

Tags: c

I created a function with lenB as one of the arguments. Within the same function when I try

```
for(i=lenB*2;i<lenA=lenB;i++)
```

I get the error 'lvalue required as left operand of assignment'
What does it mean and how do I fix it?

```
int alternate_merge(int A[],int B[],int C[],int lenA,int lenB){

    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<lenB*2;i=i+2){
        for(j=0;j<lenB;j++){
    C[i]=A[j];
    C[i+1]=B[j];
    break;
        }
    }
    k=lenB*2;
    for(i=lenB*2;i<lenA=lenB;i++){
            for(j=lenB+1;j<lenA;j++){
        C[i]=A[j];
        break;
            }
    }


return C[lenA+lenB];
}
```

Comment: The equality comparison operator is `==`, not `=`.

Comment: Is `i<lenA=lenB` a typo or a misunderstanding? From the return value I guess it is supposed to be `i<lenA+lenB`

Answer (score 1):

```
i<lenA=lenB
```

is (due to operator precedence) evaluated as

```
(i<lenA)=lenB
```

The part

```
(i<lenA)
```

generates a boolean result which isn't stored in any variable. So the next step is

"boolean-value" = lenB

where you try to assign a int to a boolean value. That's not possible.

For more about operator precedence see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

The error **'lvalue required as left operand of assignment'** basically means that you can't assign a value to something which is not an lvalue. In very general terms an lvalue is a named variable or a memory location.

Examples:

```
int a = 10; // Legal as a is an lvalue
1 = a;      // Illegal as 1 isn't an lvalue

int b = a;  // Legal as b is an lvalue

(a == b) = a; // Illegal as (a == b) isn't an lvalue but a boolean value

int *p;
p = &b; // Legal as p is an lvalue
*p = a; // Legal as *p is an lvalue
```